# How can I edit the color of search bar in nautilus gtk3?

Tags: nautilus, gtk3

i want to change search bar in nautilus to purple but i don't know how
this is my first theme still don't know my way around.

[here is a example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2078155/Screenshot%20from%202012-09-25%2021:51:03.png)

Comment: It appears that a very similar question has been asked and marked [Solved] [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12261068#post12261068).

Comment: vasa1 it was me that posted that but i was thinking that no one else would reply and i marked it as solved, stupid of me.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution for my problem in

/usr/share/themes/Ambiance-Purple/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css

i change this

```
/***********
 * infobar *
 ***********/
.info {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (shade (#dbdbdb, 1.04)),
                                     to (shade (#dbdbdb, 0.96)));
```

to this

```
/***********
 * infobar *
 ***********/
.info {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                     from (alpha (#dbdbdb, 0.0001)),
                                     to (alpha (#dbdbdb, 0.0001)));
```

sorry guys but new users aren't allowed to post images you can see them [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12264636#post12264636)

Answer (score 0):

follow this [tutorial](http://worldofgnome.org/making-gtk3-themes-part-2-the-gtk-css-and-gtk-widgets-css-files/) to learn how to make your own GTK3 theme.